# existence of the supremum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

How can I show that every upper-bounded set $A\subset \mathbb R, A\neq \emptyset$ has a supremum ? I tried by contradiction, but it isn't conclusive. I also tried to prove that $$\inf\{M\mid \forall x\in A , M\geq x\}$$ exist, but it looks equivalent than to show that $\sup A$ exist.

Comment: You cannot. Consider $\emptyset$, bounded from above by $1$, yet its supremum is $- \infty$.

Comment: What is your topological closure axiom of the reals? Because one of the variants is just this supremum property.

Comment: I corrected with $A\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @LutzL: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You could have the Cauchy sequences axiom, the nested intervals axiom or the supremums axiom. They all are equivalent. It seems that your task is to show one of the equivalences.

Comment: A (maybe) clearer version of the comment by @LutzL: Your statement is false if you replace $\Bbb{R}$ by $\Bbb{Q}$. Thus, you have to use some special property of the real numbers to prove your claim. Sometimes (usually?), what you need to show is taken as an **axiom**. Thus, we conjecture that your course/book is based on some other axiom system for the real numbers. You need to derive the statement from these axioms. If you do not tell us which axioms these are, we can not help you :(

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thank you, it's exactly that.

Comment: I don't have any specific axiom... which axioms should I have ?

Comment: Probably: Every Cauchy sequence has a limit. -- In general, the axioms of the real numbers are the axioms of a number field plus the axioms of an ordered ring plus the Archimedean axiom plus an axiom providing topological closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One proof is by bisection:

Let $(a_n,b_n)$ be a pair of element of the set and upper bound. Set $c_n=(a_n+b_n)/2$ their midpoint. Either $c_n$ is an upper bound, then $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=(a_n,c_n)$. Or there is a point $a_{n+1}\ge c_n$ in the set, then $b_{n+1}=b_n$.

Use that this sequence of pairs provides a sequence of nested intervals or use that the sequence $(b_n)$ can be shown to be Cauchy.